# TemplateBox based controllers. Not editable InputFieldBox

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, stylesheet, customization, boxes

The goal is to have controllers fully customizable from a stylesheet level. At the moment one can't add `MouseAppearace` to a `Slider` just by modifying "Slider" style. Or even to change `Appearance` of a `Button` because it is injected by `Button` function directly in boxes and overriding whatever Appearace we have in ButtonBoxOptions in a stylesheet.

So this works:

```
x = 1;
Dynamic[x]

RawBoxes @ TemplateBox[
  {Dynamic[x]}
  , "MyInput"
  , DisplayFunction :> (SliderBox[#] &)
]
```

But this doesn't, the input field is not editable:

```
RawBoxes @ TemplateBox[
  {Dynamic[x]}
  , "MyInput"
  , DisplayFunction :> (InputFieldBox[#, Number] &)
]
```

What is the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a workaround is to put whole `InputFieldBox` as a parameter and set options via `StyleBox`:

```
RawBoxes @ TemplateBox[
  { ToBoxes @ InputField[Dynamic[x]] },
  "MyInput",
  DisplayFunction :> (
    TagBox[
      StyleBox[#, InputFieldBoxOptions -> {FieldSize -> {3, 4}}],
      MouseAppearanceTag["LinkHand"]
    ] &
  )
]
```

---

#### The big picture

In addition to points at the top of the question, the following setup allows live adjustments to gui elements.

Here is an example:

```
MyInputField /: MakeBoxes[MyInputField[var_, type_, opts___], fmt_] :=
  TemplateBox[
  {MakeBoxes[InputField[var, type, opts], fmt]}, "MyInputField"
  ]

nb = CreateDocument[
  Column[
   MyInputField[Dynamic[a[#]], Number] & /@ Range@10
   ],
  
  StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
     Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
     Cell[
      StyleData["MyInputField"],
      TemplateBoxOptions -> {
        DisplayFunction :> (TagBox[
            StyleBox[#, 
             InputFieldBoxOptions -> {Background -> 
                RGBColor[1, 1, 0]}], MouseAppearanceTag["LinkHand"]] &)
        }
      ]
     }]
  ]

FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken[nb, "EditStyleDefinitions"]
```

[image]

Ok, that one could do with InputField style, but not that:

[image]